# Validating JSON for a simple view

Tags: django, django-views

I have a simple Django web application that I use for logging personal expenses. I've started writing a new view that will create a webhook to receive transactions from my bank Monzo. So every time there's a new transaction on my account Monzo send a JSON with the details to a URL I specify. And my app is to save this transaction.

As this is all that's happening, just one webhook, I decided not to use the Django REST framework and just create a view that receives the JSON from the bank and saves the transaction.

The bank resends each transaction two times. Once when the transaction first hits the account, and then usually a second time, once the transaction has been settled (fulfilled). So my view will check if the transaction already exists and then either create a new record or update existing one.

So far I've only written a few lines of code and confirmed that the JSON is received and can be accessed in the view.

My question is regarding validation. What sort of validation should I do to ensure that the JSON doesn't include anything dangerous and is safe for my view to process?

Example of transaction the bank will send to my webhook.

```
{
    "type": "transaction.created",
    "data": {
        "account_id": "acc_00008gju41AHyfLUzBUk8A",
        "amount": -350,
        "created": "2015-09-04T14:28:40Z",
        "currency": "GBP",
        "description": "Ozone Coffee Roasters",
        "id": "tx_00008zjky19HyFLAzlUk7t",
        "category": "eating_out",
        "is_load": false,
        "settled": "2015-09-05T14:28:40Z",
        "merchant": {
            "address": {
                "address": "98 Southgate Road",
                "city": "London",
                "country": "GB",
                "latitude": 51.54151,
                "longitude": -0.08482400000002599,
                "postcode": "N1 3JD",
                "region": "Greater London"
            },
            "created": "2015-08-22T12:20:18Z",
            "group_id": "grp_00008zIcpbBOaAr7TTP3sv",
            "id": "merch_00008zIcpbAKe8shBxXUtl",
            "logo": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/527043602623389696/68_SgUWJ.jpeg",
            "emoji": "",
            "name": "The De Beauvoir Deli Co.",
            "category": "eating_out"
        }
    }
}
```

This is how far I've got with my code this morning, so not far, but you can see where I'm going with this.

```
@csrf_exempt
def index(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)

    # Check if transaction already exists and if so then update.
    if Transaction.objects.filter(monzo_id=data['data']['id']).exists()
        transaction = Transaction.objects.filter(monzo_id=data['data']['id']) # Do I need to check there's only one record?
        transaction.data = data
        transaction.updated = datetime.datetime.now()
        transaction.settled = data['data']['settled']
        transaction.save()
    else:
        transaction = Transaction(
            created = datetime.datetime.now(),
            monzo_id = data['data']['settled']
            .... #More will go here...
            )
        transaction.save()

    #logger.warning(data['type'])
    #logger.warning(data['data']['merchant']['address']['city'])
    #logger.warning(data['data'])
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'content': data}) # Sending data to view just for debugging purposes
```

My models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False, blank=False)

class Merchant(models.Model):
    monzo_id = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False, blank=False)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    logo = models.URLField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True) # Should this be URL field?
    data = models.TextField(blank = False, null=False)

class Transaction(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    account = # To be completed
    monzo_id = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=False)
    settled = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=False, blank=False)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=False, blank=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False, blank=False)
    is_load = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)
    merchant_id = models.ForeignKey(Merchant, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    data = models.TextField(blank = False, null=False)
```

Comment: why you didn't use Django REST framework?
with that you can validate your json in serializer

Comment: Exactly, you should use a ModelSerializer. It’s kind of the same as a ModelForm except it takes json as data instead of a `request.POST` querydict. So it can validate you’re data (like a form’s clean() method, it has a `validate` method).

Comment: Amy chance of some tips on how to do this with django rest framework so I dont have to trawl thru documentation